# In openlayer, Bing opacity change but Google's not

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-maps, maps, openlayers

i am developping an aplication that using both Google and Bing maps 
when i want to change map's opacity ,i have got a problem with openlayers. Bing maps is working but Google maps is not 
there are all code with maps in the below,

```
map.baseLayer.setOpacity(newOpacity);
```

but i know that this code doesn't work.
 Thank you for help in advance.

```
 var googlePhysical = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
           "Google Physical", {
               type: google.maps.MapTypeId.TERRAIN,
               numZoomLevels: numZoomLevels,
               transparent: 'true',
               alpha: true,
               transitionEffect: "resize",

           }
       );

var googleStreets = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
           "Google Streets", { numZoomLevels: numZoomLevels, transparent: 'true' }
       );

var googleHybrid = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
           "Google Hybrid", { type: google.maps.MapTypeId.HYBRID, numZoomLevels: numZoomLevels, sphericalMercator: true, transparent: 'true' }
       );

var googleSatellite = new OpenLayers.Layer.Google(
           "Google Satellite", { type: google.maps.MapTypeId.SATELLITE, numZoomLevels: numZoomLevels, transparent: 'true' }
       );

  var Bingroad = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
    name: "Bing Road", key: apiKey, type: "Road", numZoomLevels: numZoomLevels, transparent: 'true', opacity: 1
});

var Binghybrid = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
    name: "Bing Hybrid", key: apiKey, type: "AerialWithLabels", numZoomLevels: numZoomLevels, transparent: 'true', opacity: 1
});

var Bingaerial = new OpenLayers.Layer.Bing({
    name: "Bing Aerial", key: apiKey, type: "Aerial", numZoomLevels: numZoomLevels, transparent: 'true', opacity:1
});
 map.addLayers([googleSatellite,googlePhysical, googleStreets, googleHybrid]);
map.addLayers([Binghybrid, Bingaerial,Bingroad]);
```

Comment: i didnt found , still .i am waiting your answers.

Comment: maybe you could simulate this in jsfiddle.net for us to play around...